Removing Gradle with all dependencies
I have installed Gradle via Synaptic Package Manager. During the installation process, two auxiliary packages were installed, plus a large amount of different dependencies, and the process was quite lengthy. Since the Gradle build was old (4.4.1) and useless, I removed it, via Synaptic. But I'm not sure that Synaptic removed all the dependencies. How I can check this? I have Java 17 and JDK installed.
EDIT:
I tried a simulated dry run apt-get -s autoremove gradle, and this gives absolutely unacceptable results - the removal a plenty of legitimate packages.

I have solved problem using Synaptic Package Manager: File > History > select date --> copy and create list of installed packages. Then using command:
sudo apt purge $(awk '{print $1}' <list)


sudo apt autoremove will remove all packages that were installed to satisfy a dependency, if there are no packages still depending on them.
Here's a simplified example.
One installs package A, which depends on package Z. Package Z is automatically installed.
Then, one installs package B, which also depends on package Z, but since Z is already installed, no action is needed.
When one uninstalls package A, Z is still in use by package B, and not vulnerable to apt autoremove.
When package B is uninstalled, and no other package is dependent on package Z, an apt autoremove will remove Z.

I tried to do a simulated dry run apt-get -s autoremove gradle, and this gives absolutely unacceptable results - the removal a plenty of legitimate packages.

@minto That probably means you have installed your system using metapackages to pull in larger sets of packages, but then removed the metapackages themselves. This might happen if your system is upgraded from a previous major release. You can use apt-mark manual <package name> to mark the packages you wish to keep; it might be a chore, but once done, the dependency tracking (and tools like apt-get autoremove) will again work as they're supposed to.

@telcoM The main problem is that, with the exception of a few applications, I don't know which packages are needed for my existing programs and which are remnants left by Gradle. How can I track list of additional packages that was installed by Gradle? (to separate file)

I forgot that I can do this via Synaptic Package Manager, so I've solved problem.

@minto You can also review /var/log/dpkg.log and its rotated versions, find where you installed gradle and remove all packages that were installed at the same time it was. That should work even on headless systems with very minimal tools installed.
